# In C++11, how to print a character given its Unicode code?

Tags: c++, unicode, printing, hex

I am sure this is a dumb question, but is there a straightforward way to print a Unicode character in C++ given its hex code? For instance: I know that the code for ❤ is 0x2764. Is there a way I can use its code to print it (either via printf or on a stream)?

For the record, I can print the character by writing:

```
cout << "\u2764" << endl;
```

but that requires knowing the value at compile time rather than using a variable.

Thanks

Comment: UTF-8 != Unicode, there's no UTF-8 in your question.

Answer (score 2):

From a comment I see you're on OS X, which uses UTF-8 and has a sufficiently complete implementation of the C++11 library (libc++) for the following to work.

```
#include <codecvt>  // wstring_convert, codecvt_utf8
#include <iostream> // cout

int main() {
  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> convert;

  std::cout << convert.to_bytes(static_cast<char32_t>(0x2764)) << '\n';
}
```

This depends on the console working properly with UTF-8, which OS X's does.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to output `wchar_t` to the stream.

```
#include <iostream>

std::wcout << static_cast<wchar_t>(0x2764) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Hmm, 3 downvotes make me wonder... Have I hurt anybody's feelings? Would any following downvoter leave a comment on what's really wrong please?

Comment: It's mostly correct, except for the fact that `wchar_t` is not necessarily Unicode (hence `char32_t`) Also, MSVC++ is broken beyond belief when it comes to Unicode console I/O, so naive people might test your code, see nothing, and assume you messed up.

Comment: I didn't downvote (in fact, to balance I upvoted), however it doesn't work for me (MacOS/Darwin).

Comment: This is not sufficient. a) wchar_t values are not necessarily Unicode values. b) wcout is required only to handle characters from the current locale, so you should set the locale appropriately (and there is no portable locale specified to support this character). c) Certain platforms don't necessarily work correctly even when you set the locale.

Comment: Thank you all for the explanation. Surely my answer is rather naive for such a complicated issue as Unicode in pre-11 C++. bames53's way should work much better.